# Get Users where are not in role admin and simpleuser

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-2.0, roles

I am using .Net Core 2.1 and I want to exclude the users that have the role "Admin" and "SimpleUser" I had followed this example [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004516/net-core-2-1-identity-get-all-users-with-their-associated-roles)

How i can add the where part?
So far i have tried this with no luck:

```
 ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = new SelectList( _context.Users.Include(u=>u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u=>u.Role).Where(o=>o.UserRoles!="Admin"), "Id", "Company", products.ApplicationUserId);
```

[image]

ApplicationUserRole Class:

```
 public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If you see the image on my question the error starts in the first part on my where

Comment: What is the type of UserRoles? Is it an entity? A String?

Comment: public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

Comment: Since the `UserRoles` is of type `ICollection<ApplicationUserRole>` you probably need something like `.Where(o => !o.UserRoles.Any(r => r.Role == "Admin"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message in the attached image suggests that  `u.UserRoles` is not a string, try something like `u.UserRoles.All(r=>r.RoleId!="Admin" && r.RoleId!="SimpleUser")` in your `Where`

Comment: Your solution is working but with this . r.Role.Name != "Admin"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check that none of the roles are of "Admin" or "SimpleUser"

```
ViewData["ApplicationUserId"] = new SelectList( _context.Users.Include(u=>u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u=>u.Role).Where(o => !o.UserRoles.Any(r => (r.Role == "Admin") || (r.Role == "SimpleUser"))), "Id", "Company", products.ApplicationUserId);
```