# ASP.NET Core 2.1 displaying users and roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Trying to display users along with their role in core 2.1, I followed the example [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004516/net-core-2-1-identity-get-all-users-with-their-associated-roles) . I have no errors but I'm not getting user roles to display. I think it could be my view, for some reason my code returns an email address instead of user role.

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, 
ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,
ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>

{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultUI()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page )
{
   var users = from u in _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role) select u;

   return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserRoles)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put everything inside `ApplicatonUser` class. First rearrange your model classes as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Now `UserRoles` is a collection, you cannot display this with `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserRoles)`, rather you have to iterate over this collection as follows:

```
@model List<ApplicationUser>
@{
    foreach (ApplicationUser applicationUser in Model)
    {
        <div>UserName : @applicationUser.UserName</div>
        <br/>
        <h4>User's Role</h4>
        <hr/>
        foreach (ApplicationUserRole applicationUserRole in applicationUser.UserRoles)
        {
            <div>RoleName: @applicationUserRole.Role.Name</div>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize my classes were inside my ApplicationUser class, I can see it now with the view. Thanks, its just very little resources on roles in asp 2.1