# Assigning a user to a Role inside asp.net core will return this error "You do not have access to this resource."

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I created a new asp.net core web application which uses individual user accounts. now i am trying to implement a simple role assignment scenario.

so i register a test user, where the user got added inside the AspNetUser table:-
[image]

then i add a new Role named "Administrator" inside the AspNetRole:-
[image]

then i added a new AspNetUserRole to link the user to the Role:-
[image]

then i added the following Authorize annotation on the About action method:-

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
        public IActionResult About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }
```

but when i try to access the About action method using the user, i got this error:-

> You do not have access to this resource."

**EDIT**

Here is the `startup.cs` , which i have not modified, so i think it contain the built-in code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication2.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How was your user authenticated?

Comment: @hugo using a yahoo email address

Comment: Need to see how your startup.cs is configured

Comment: Publish your startup.cs and your login method

Comment: @hugo i edited my question with the `startup.cs` code.. thnx

Comment: your startup.cs misses configuration. you should check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @hugo can you explain what is missing exactly? as i created the new application and i define to use individual user account, so i thought/assume that everything should be pre-configured,,,or this is not the case?

Comment: @hugo can you advice on my above comment?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you manually create role and link role in `AspNetUserRole`table after creating your user . Please don't forget to **Logout user and login again** , so role claims will get/update the new added role .

Comment: yes i have manually created the role inside the `AspNetRole` table and the link between the Role and the User inside the `AspNetUserRole` table.. i tried to logout and re-login but it did not work.. not sure what is wrong?

Comment: can you advice on my above comments?thnx

Comment: @testtest , not sure , i follow your steps , it works after logout and sign in again

Comment: ok i see,, and is your `startup.cs` similar to the one i have? i have edited my question and i provided how my `startup.cs` looks like..thnx

Comment: can you advice on my above comment ?

Comment: you try close the browser and start again?

Answer (score 1):

Your identity service is not configured for roles. *AddDefaultIdentity* cannot handle roles. You need *AddIdentity*

Instead of:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

**Try:**

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Add IdentityRole :

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

## Long Answer

For properly using of roles/policies, you need to follow the below steps:

- configure ApplicationDbContext for using IdentityRole
- configure Identity service to use IdentityRole
- configure application cookie
- define authorization policies
- configure authorization for razor pages

#### Notice : if you are using razor pages, Authorization attributes must be applied to the PageModel model not the actions

before proceeding with the solution, it is worth to mention that it is a best practice to use custom user and role models instead of IdentityUser and IdentityModel. This will help you add custom fields to the user and role easily.

So, first lets create our custom user and role models:

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    //custom fields can be defined here
}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole
{
    //custom fields can be defined here
}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can start with configuring ApplicationDbContext:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, AppUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // AppUserRole relationship solution from so
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004516/net-core-2-1-identity-get-all-users-with-their-associated-roles/51005445#51005445

        builder.Entity<AppUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

- configuring Identity

```cs
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(ops =>
{
    ops.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

    // Lockout settings
    ops.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    ops.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 9;

    ops.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    // User settings
    ops.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

- configure application cookie

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
{
     // Cookie settings
     ops.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
     ops.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

     // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults the path to /Account/Login.
     ops.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";

     // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
     ops.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
     ops.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

- define authorization policies

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(ops =>
{
    ops.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy =>
    {
         policy.RequireRole("Administrator");
    });
});
```

Now it is possible to use roles/policies in different ways:

1- define authorization policies in startup

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(ops =>
    {
        ops.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", "Administrator");
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

2- apply authorization attributes on actions in case of MVC

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
    return View();
}
```

3- or apply policy on PageModel for Razor Pages

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "Administrator")]
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    //-----
}
```

### [UPDATE]

following to your comment below;
Let's consider that you will develop a news website management panel; basically you will need roles like Admins to manage the site settings and Authors to post the news pages, and probably Managers to approve the posted news. With this scenario you can survive with the default Identity settings and role based authorization.

But for example; if you need to allow only authors with more than 100 posted articles and are older than 25 to be able to approve their posts without the Managers approval then you need to customize the IdentityUser and use policy/claim based authorization, in this case the long answer will help you more to develop the application.

you can read more about authorization in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: thanks a lot for the valuable reply and help.. but i am not sure why the steps you mentioned in the "Long Answer" are already done for us when we create a new asp.net core project which uses individual user accounts? second point when we should use the "Short answer" steps and when we should use the "Long answer" steps? can you provide more details please?

Comment: @testtest I updated the answer by a simple sample to explain the short/long answers, hope it will help :)

Comment: ok i see, now those topics are somehow new to me... So if  chose the "long answer" and i use the policy/claim based authorization ,, will i still be able to use the simple authorization, for example that certain action methods can only be accessed by users who are inside a role named "Admin" when needed?

Comment: yes you are free to use it as you need, additionally you will be able to use the more advanced authorization simply like the role authorization e.g. `[Authorize(Policy = "OnlySeniorAuthors")]`

Comment: btw, if the app doesn't really need advanced authorization it is better to go with the simple solution to avoid unnecessary complexity

Comment: Ok thanks again for the help. to be honest i am having difficulties in understanding how claim works, for example on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2 then provide this policy `options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));` and they explain it as follow `..that of a minimum age, which is supplied as a parameter to the requirement.` so i am not sure how the user age will be stored and transferred within the application ?

Comment: well, in simple words; first you create the age policy "AtLeast21", then you create the MinimumAgeHandler that will calculate the logged in user age (date of birth is stored in the users data), then you register the handler in startup so it will be triggered wherever you use the relevant policy.