# ASP.NET Core 2.2 authorize attribute with roles not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, roles, asp.net-core-2.2, authorize-attribute

I am migrating an ASP.NET 4.6 MVC app to Asp.Net Core 2.2. I have managed to migrate all the data. I have checked the AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, and AspNetUserRoles tables and they have the migrated data. I scaffolded the Login and AccessDenied pages using the Razor Class Library as per the offical docs

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio]

My scenario is as follows: I have a controller named Leads which has an action named Create. I want only those users who belong to the CreateLead role to access the Create action. For testing purposes I have configured it to be the default page so when the application starts it will redirect the user to the Login page because the action is protected by the Authorize attribute. If the user is authenticated they will be redirected to the Leads contoller.

I can successfully login using my username and password stored in the AspNetUsers table. If I add the Authorize attribute **without** specifying the **Role** property and **without adding the AddRoles extension in the Startup class** I am being redirected to the Create view successfully.

```
 [Authorize]
 public IActionResult Create()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

Startup class

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SalesIdentityContext>();
```

However, if I specify the **Roles property and add the AddRoles extension to the Startup class** as shown below the browser will not load the view. Its giving me the following error: The webpage at https://localhost:44388/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address: ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

```
[Authorize( Roles = "CreateLead")]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<SalesIdentityContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SalesIdentityContext>();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        // Add application services.
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppLogger<>), typeof(LoggerAdapter<>));
        services.AddScoped<ILeadService, LeadService>();

        services.AddHttpClient("my_api_client_name", c => 
        {
            c.BaseAddress = "my_api_uri");
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            ListAllRegisteredServices(app);
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            //app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Leads}/{action=Create}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**I have a custom identity class named User which is extending the IdentityUser class. On the User class I have added FirstName and LastName properties.**

I have checked the AspNetUserRoles table and can confirm that both the UserId and RoleId are available.

**Visual Studio Output**
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
WebApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel:Information: User logged in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Executed handler method OnPostAsync, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.LocalRedirectResult.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.LocalRedirectResultExecutor:Information: Executing LocalRedirectResult, redirecting to /.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Executed page /Account/Login in 10100.4486ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed endpoint 'Page: /Account/Login'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 10232.1354ms 302

Comment: We had same problem last week. You didn't add authrotisation in your start up..Change this line as follow:
``services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddAuthorization();``

Comment: _“The official documentation says we should append the AddRoles to add Role services”_ – That is correct. `AddDefaultIdentity` does not add roles support by default. When you say, it is not working, what exactly isn’t working? What behavior do you expect to happen? _“If I specify the Roles property I am being redirected to the access denied page”_ – That would be the correct behavior: If you are signed in and don’t have the required role, you will be redirect to access denied.

Comment: @poke The user has the required role but still being denied access. I checked the AspNetUserRoles table both the role id and user id are available so I expect to be taken to that Create view.

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55999860/5519026

Comment: Why do you comment the ` //.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`?

Comment: Also, 1.  Make sure the table field `AspNetRoles.Name`(instead of `AspNetRoles.Id`) is `CreateLead`.  2. Make sure you have logout and login again.

Comment: @Munhu Try debugging your application, and inside of a (unauthorized) controller action, look at `User.Claims`. You can see what claims actually exist for the signed-in user. Check if there are actual role claims in the identity, and if they are, that they are written correctly (they are case-sensitive by default). Then report back and we’ll see what could be the problem.

Comment: @itminus I have re-phrased my question check again. I can confirm that the name of the role in the AspNetRoles table is CreateLead

Comment: @poke I have re-phrased my question. If I add .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() in Startup the browser can't load the action with the Authorize attribute even without specifying the roles in the Authorize like [Athorize].

Comment: _“the browser will not load the view. Its giving me the following error: […] ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR”_ – Can you check the _server_ logs for that one? There should be some exception in there.

Comment: @poke There are no erros in the log files. The last logged item for each request is: 2019-06-11 08:18:36 ::1 POST /Identity/Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2F 44388 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:65.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/65.0 https://localhost:44388/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 302 0 0 6613

Comment: That’s your IIS logs. You will need to look at the ASP.NET Core server logs.

Comment: Where are they located? I am running the application from Visual Studio 2019. I have added the output to the last section of this question since it cannot fit in a comment.

Comment: @Munhu I tried your code. But your code works pretty fine for me. Is there a minimal demo that reproduces?

Comment: Its a big project. Let me start a new project and report back.

Comment: I turned off https in VS and then got this error: HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long. The user was a member of 312 roles. I removed the user from most of the roles for testing purposes after I read this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020943/http-400-bad-request-request-header-too-long-response-to-http-request. It's not really ASP.NET but it gave me a clue. Now I can login and the roles are working fine but I need the admin user to be a member of all roles. The roles are many because they are granular e.g CanCreate, CanView, CanEdit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

under

```
  app.UseAuthentication();
```

Comment: OP specifies Core 2.2 and app.UseAuthorization was not available in  that version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationappbuilderextensions.useauthorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2