# User List with Role in .Net Core 3.1 Identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity

Can I get a list of all the users with the associated roles in .Net Core 3.1 from Identity? I haven't found any solution that works.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried, and how it didnt work.

Comment: Yes, i tried this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004516/net-core-2-1-identity-get-all-users-with-their-associated-roles?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customize Identity Model and add navigation properties.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

and then add required configuration.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
    {
        // Each User can have many entries in the UserRole join table
        b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
            .WithOne(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
            .IsRequired();
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
    {
        // Each Role can have many entries in the UserRole join table
        b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
            .WithOne(e => e.Role)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
            .IsRequired();            
    });
}
```

and then you can use joins to query users with roles. More information on adding navigation proprieties can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-all-navigation-properties)