# Can we get ping identity user list in .net core?

Tags: .net

I want get Ping Identity user list in .net core,
But I does not getting any related documents
please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by ping? can you further explain? or check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004516/net-core-2-1-identity-get-all-users-with-their-associated-roles

Comment: Yes Ping Identity. It just like AWS Cognito