# Querying users and all the roles assigned to each user

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to list all users, along with all the roles each user has.

I know I could query the users table, and then use `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` to query the roles for each user. But this would be incredibly inefficient. This should be possible with a single query?

I start with something like this:

```
Users = await (from u in DbContext.Users
               orderby u.Name
               select new UserSummaryViewModel
               {
                   Id = u.Id,
                   Name = u.Name,
                   Roles = u.UserRoles  // ERROR HERE!
                       .Select(ur => ur.Role.Name)
               })
               .ToListAsync();
```

This won't work because `ApplicationUser` has no `UserRoles` navigation property. So I changed it to this:

```
Users = await (from u in DbContext.Users
               orderby u.Name
               select new UserSummaryViewModel
               {
                   Id = u.Id,
                   Name = u.Name,
                   Roles = DbContext.UserRoles
                       .Where(ur => ur.UserId == u.Id)
                       .Select(ur => ur.Role.Name)  // ERROR HERE!
               })
               .ToListAsync();
```

But this won't work because `UserRole` has no `Role` navgiation property.

I'm not sure why Microsoft didn't add those navigation properties. But it seems like this shouldn't be so difficult.

Can anyone see a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004516/net-core-2-1-identity-get-all-users-with-their-associated-roles) for .Net core 2.1. I think it is still valid:
You should change the ApplicatinUser And ApplicationRole classes to include the relationship then you can easily query like this:

```
var usersWithRoles = userManager.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).ToList();
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Still don't know why it's this hard, but I will dig into this solution.