# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type: When using Anonymous method with lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-8.0

I'm working on an application on .NET Core 8 with EF which uses authentication with individual accounts.

I'm trying to display a list of users with their roles. Here's my code. Here's an anonymous method with a lambda expression:

```
public IList<User> Users { get; set; } = default!;

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    IQueryable<User> users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new User()
    {
        Username = c.UserName,
        Role = async () =>
        {
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c);
            return roles.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    });

    User = await users.ToListAsync();
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

How can I fix this error?

There're answers which explain how to get all the users in different ways. But I'm asking this question because I want to know what to do if I get a similar error in a lambda expression somewhere else.

Comment: Instead of your current way, you should [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) the `User` with linked `Role`. With this way (even if it is not working), you will call N times (based on `Users` count) to query the `Role` data.

Comment: Also, please do share what is `Users` in the `UserManager`, the `User` class. Thanks

Comment: @Yong Shun The Users in the _userManager is a Microsoft inbuilt object that comes within the _userManager. Not a custom class of mine.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [.NET Core 2.1 Identity get all users with their associated roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004516/net-core-2-1-identity-get-all-users-with-their-associated-roles) With eager loading, you should able to assign value to `Role`: `Role = c.Roles.FirstOrDefault()?.Name` without async calling the `GetRolesAsync` method.

Comment: @Yong Shun Did the IdentityUser used to have a Roles property? It doesn't now. I'm using .net core 8.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, otherwise you may consider for async expression in `.Select`. It should be something like: `.Select(async x => { var user = new User(); user.Role = /* Get role */; return user; })`

Comment: `Role = async () => {...}` -> `Role =  (await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c)).FirstOrDefault()` and mark containing lambda as async (`Users.Select(async c => ...`).

Comment: @Yong Shun Yes, there're other ways to code this. But I'm asking this question because I want to know what to do if I get a similar error with a lambda expression.

Comment: @Guru Stron I can't call FirstOrDefault() on the await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(). That's why I have seperated it to two lines.

Comment: @Daneesha you can, you need parenthesis (check my code carefully). Note that this will make the code compile (and possibly even work) but in general it is bad approach.

Comment: @Guru Stron I'm sorry. I was wrong about not being able to call FirstOrDefault(). It can be done. But if I modify the code as you have mentioned I get a compiler error saying 'Async lambda expressions cannot be converted to expression trees'.

Comment: @Daneesha Then you are out of options, yes (TBH have never tried to use async with exrpression trees).